# ios app crashes when loading image from html string

Tags: ios, memory, warnings

in my app in a  web view page i am trying to load images from an html string. There are around 27 images. The app is getting crashed and in the error report it says as memorywarning2. How to overcome this problem....Please help me friends

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Comment: it is just showing memorywarning2......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably loading too many, too large images into memory at one time.

Unless you really need a web view, you could use `UIImageView`s in a `UIScrollView` and handle the memory usage yourself.

If you must use a web view, maybe you could use smaller images.

Comment: thanks, but i have some text and image in my html file, in that case i have to use webview only, with large images. How to manage this...

Comment: I'd flip it around and say that since your app crashes when using a web view with large images, you have to use something else. UIKit provides excellent support for controlling memory while working with huge images, so if you must use large images, you also must use something other than a web view. Apple has a session from both WWDC 2010 and 2011 about this (session 104 in both cases).